# If $f$ has a pole of order $N$ at $z=a$ then $\exp{f}$ has an essential singularity at $z=a$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show that if $f$ has a pole of order $N$ at $z=a$ then $\exp{f}$ has an essential singularity at $z=a$.

My idea is to write $f(x)=\sum_{k=-N}^{\infty} a_k (z-a)^k$ so that $$\exp f(x) = \sum_{n\mathop=0}^{\infty} \frac 1 {n!}\left(\sum_{k =-N}^{\infty}a_k (z-a)^k\right)^n$$ where $N \ge 1$.

If I can show that there are infinitely many negative degree terms in the expansion then I am done. So I just need to show that there won't be some weird cancellation that could occur. I am not sure what the best way of going about this is though.

I realise there may be better ways of proving the statement but I want to see if this can be made to work.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ has a pole at $a$, then for each $\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}\ep>0$, the image
$f(B'_\ep(a))$ of the deleted $\ep$-neighbourhood of $a$
contains a set of the form $\{z:|z|> R\}$. So the image $\exp(f(B_{\ep(a)}))$ contains the set $\{\exp(z):|z|>R\}$. This
contains sequences tending to zero and to $\infty$, so $f(z)$
cannot tend to a finite limit, nor to $\infty$, as $z\to a$, so has
neither a removable singularity nor a pole.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to observe this: since $f$ has a pole at $a$, then $\lim_{z\to a}f(z)=\infty$ and therefore, for each $w\in\mathbb C$, you can find a sequence $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of complex numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n=\infty$ and that $\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}e^{f(z_n)}=w$. Therefore, $e^f$ has an essential singularity at $1$.

Comment: I don't follow. Why can such a sequence be found?

Comment: @user1488 Because the exponential function is so surjective (other than the fact that its range doesn't include $0$) that its restriction to any set of the form $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,|\,|z|>R\}$ is still surjective (with the same restriction as before). And because if $f$ has a pole at $a$, then, for every $\varepsilon>0$, $f\bigl(D(a,\varepsilon)\setminus\{a\}\bigr)$ contains some set of the form $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,|\,|z|>R\}$.

Comment: both answers given use the last sentence, but at the probable level of the OP, why is it true?